# Putting a Google Maps Marker position with a Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to put a marker inside my map, and I'm passing the javascript variable through another php page via clicking the `<ul>`, when I copy the alert result (example: {lat: -25.4025, lng: -49.2643} ) and put directly inside the 'position' field it works fine, but when I put the variable on it, it does not.

```
PHP
$History_Assoc = mysqli_fetch_array($HistoryQuery);


      echo '<ul class="repoFolder" data-value=" {lat: '.(float)$History_Assoc['latitude'].', lng: '.(float)$History_Assoc['longitude'] .'}  ">';
      echo '<br>';



JAVASCRIPT
var folders = document.getElementsByClassName("repoFolder");
for (let i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
  folders[i].onclick = function() {rootFolder.call(this)}; // note that I am passing in the context to rootFolder. 
}

function rootFolder() {

  var variable =  this.getAttribute('data-value');

  alert(variable);

  var markersHistory = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: variable,
    map: map,
    icon: iconBlue2,
  });
}
```

Comment: Are you variables holding the correct data? Are you able to check the result it's producing?

Comment: yes, When I "alert" the variable it shows the coordinates, when I copy the same coordinates and put inside de position field it works, but when I put the variable it does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a problem parsing the JSON from the data-value attributes in your markup. There are a couple of ways you could handle this, but I think the easiest would be to embed the latitude and longitude values as two separate data attributes, then use the Google Maps LatLng object to specify the coordinates for your marker. That way you can avoid the various JSON pitfalls. Here's an example:

HTML:

```
<ul class="repoFolder" data-lat="-25.4025" data-lng="-49.2643">
    <li>Clicky</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
function rootFolder() 
{
    var latitude =  this.getAttribute('data-lat');
    var longitude =  this.getAttribute('data-lng');

    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    var markersHistory = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map
    });
}
```